# Flex: Listening for events from a yet-to-be-bound property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I've got a class like this:

```
class Foo extends UIComponent {
    var someDispatcher:*;
    ...
}
```

And I want to listen for events fired by `someDispatcher`... But, of course, `someDispatcher` may not be bound until "later":

```
<components:Foo someDispatcher="{someOtherComponent}" />
```

What's the best way to listen for events `from someDispatcher`?

I know I *could* bind to `someDispatcher`, then wire up the event handlers when it's updated... Or I could use getters/setters... But those all seem very complex. I'm hoping there's a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making someDispatcher bindable itself is the simplest/most straightforward solution. You can set event handlers for someDispatcher in the handler for the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [ChangeWatcher](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html) class will be helpful here...